# how to identify if PHP is using VC6 or VC9 and wheather its threaded safe or non threaded safe?

Tags: php

I am trying to download an extension for this I need to know my installation uses VC6 or VC9?  And whether it is threaded safe or non threaded safe. PHP version I am using is 5.3.5. I did look into the phpinfo result page,  I see one reference regarding it as: `MSVC6 (Visual C++ 6.0)`

Does this mean my php installation uses VC6? How will I come to know about threaded safe Vs non threaded safe?

Comment: Download correct version for Windows OS + IIS from [_windows.php.net_](http://windows.php.net/download/). There you can obtain correct build for Windows OS. Your message tells that your PHP was build with `MSVC6` compiler. If some of vendor extensions assebled with different compiler, which is not compatible with your PHP compiler, then you probably can't use them, until you find compatible build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just open a command shell, go to the php directory and run

```
php -r phpinfo();
```

the output contains amongst other things

```
PHP Version => 5.4.7
[...]
Build Date => Sep 12 2012 23:44:56
Compiler => MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture => x86
[...]
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => enabled
```

You can do the same thing in a script served by the webserver via

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

edit: and yes, the `Compiler:` line is reliable, if it says `MSVC6` then it usually is right...